# Unable to run terminal commands from Java for latex

Tags: java, linux, shell, terminal, latex

Latex file: **0.tex** content:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial p_{dyn}}{\partial n} = A
\end{equation}  
\end{document}
```

Shell file: **0.sh** content:

```
latex /u/b/basnet/Desktop/0.tex
dvipng /u/b/basnet/Desktop/0.dvi
```

Command in Terminal:

```
>chmod 755 /u/b/basnet/Desktop/0.sh
>/u/b/basnet/Desktop/0.sh
```

Output:
Image, Dvi and other files generated by latex. You can see in the blue window.

[image]

Problem:
This works only via terminal not by executing the command via Java program.

Java Program Code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 755 /u/b/basnet/Desktop/0.sh");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/u/b/basnet/Desktop/0.sh");
System.out.println("Script executed successfully");
```

Output:

```
run:
Script executed successfully
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

The first line of the code i.e. making the file executable works fine as I cross-checked. But second line where the script file contains the latex command doesn't work when running via Java. I need to generate those files through my program.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this has to do something with environment, I'm not too deep into all this OS stuff, but I think I have a solution which worked for your example on my pc:

You have to change the names of the programs to the full paths for the use in your shell-file, because the java runtime doesn't find them. For example:

```
/Library/TeX/texbin/latex /u/basnet/Desktop/0.tex
```

The only thing that goes wrong is, that the output files appear one folder above where the tex file is located, which means you have to change either the output destination or the line for the dvi execution.

If you don't find the path for the programs, open a bash and type

```
which latex
```

and

```
which diving
```